# redundant number in the border

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithms

I have a piece of latex code and I would like to remove the redundant number 1 form top left of the border. How can I do this?

```
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\centering
\small
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
    \node[draw, text height=2ex, minimum width=46mm, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=3ex] (headingCBP) at (0,0) {\progHeader{$d$}};
    \node[below=0.5ex of headingCBP] (textCBP) {%
        \begin{minipage}[h]{46mm}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \WHILE{$d$}
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \ENDWHILE
                \RETURN{$f$}                
            \end{algorithmic} 
        \end{minipage}
    }; 

    \node[draw, text height=2ex, minimum width=68mm, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=3ex] (headingFSP) at (6.6,0) {\progHeader{$f$}}; 
    \node[below=0.5ex of headingFSP] (textFSP) {%
        \begin{minipage}[h]{68mm}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
         \FORALL{$f$}
            \FORALL{$f$}
                \IF{there does not exist $f$ such that $g$} 
                    \RETURN{$d$}
                \ENDIF
            \ENDFOR
        \ENDFOR
        \RETURN{$d$};
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{minipage}
    }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{algorithm}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Too long for a comment.</sub>

I do not see an additional "1":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}

\providecommand\progHeader{}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\centering
\small
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
    \node[draw, text height=2ex, minimum width=46mm, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=3ex] (headingCBP) at (0,0) {\progHeader{$d$}};
    \node[below=0.5ex of headingCBP] (textCBP) {%
        \begin{minipage}[h]{46mm}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \WHILE{$d$}
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \STATE{$d$;}
                \ENDWHILE
                \RETURN{$f$}                
            \end{algorithmic} 
        \end{minipage}
    }; 

    \node[draw, text height=2ex, minimum width=68mm, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=3ex] (headingFSP) at (6.6,0) {\progHeader{$f$}}; 
    \node[below=0.5ex of headingFSP] (textFSP) {%
        \begin{minipage}[h]{68mm}
            \begin{algorithmic}[1]
         \FORALL{$f$}
            \FORALL{$f$}
                \IF{there does not exist $f$ such that $g$} 
                    \RETURN{$d$}
                \ENDIF
            \ENDFOR
        \ENDFOR
        \RETURN{$d$};
            \end{algorithmic}
        \end{minipage}
    }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]